# move ad location based on browser width or device

Tags: javascript, adsense

Is there a way to dynamically generate adsense ads in different locations on the page based on browser width or device?

Google Developers resource provides an article on 'dynamically-served JavaScript' which allows you to serve up different ads based on the user-agent. But it doesn't go into any detail on whether those ads can be served into different parts of the code.

Essentially, what I want to do is have three ads load in a particular parts of the page at 'desktop' size and different ads show up at different locations when the site collapse to mobile size - all without doing any Google-disallowed nonsense like hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have containers where those ads go. You control the position of those containers. You can use CSS media queries to specify different positions for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a half solution but there's serious issues that I'll explain below. If anyone has a much better solution that would be great.

This solution uses jQuery to "copy" the iframe of an adSence ad and "paste" it into a placeholder div based on browser size.

```
<script>
if(window.innerWidth < 700){

$("#adSource").find("iframe").appendTo("#ad");

$("#adSource").remove();
}
</script>
```

When the browser loads with a width less than 700, this takes the iframe within a div called #adSource and appends it to a div with the id #ad. It then removes the iframe from within #adSource.

The draw backs to this are as follows:

- only works about 3/4 of the time. The iframes sometimes don't load quick enough and the jQuery fails
- increases load time about a second. With ads already on the page slowing this down this can be drastic
- there's no documentation as to whether or not Google allows this technique.

I'm also looking for a solution so if you find anything better please let me know.

Comment: funny that you, of all people, ended up answering this zack.